# AVL Tree , changing root causes segmentation error

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am implementing a binary tree and I want to use AVL to balance my tree. I insert the data correctly in my tree however when I want to perform the AVL operations I get segmentation error.

here is my sample code for Right rotation. I am using unique_ptr for left child, right child and root.

```
  TreeNode<T>* z = node -> parent -> parent;
  TreeNode<T>* y = node -> parent;
  TreeNode<T>* x = node;

  z -> rightChild.reset(nullptr); // Delete the pointer to rightChild
  z -> parent = nullptr; // set the parent to null
  root.reset(y); // change the root to y
  y -> setLeftChild(z); // set the left child to z
```

Is there anything missing from this?

Comment: Please provide stack trace. Also what is the type of `rightChild`.

Comment: Rightchild is unique pointer of type TreeNode

Comment: Am afraid this is not enough code to figure out the problem. Please show us more code and the stack trace indicating which line the segfault occurs. If I have to take a stab in the dark, I'll guess the segfault is because you reset the rightChild of z (which I presume is y - not sure), and hence y now goes out of scope. When you reference y again on the last line, you end up with a segfault because it has been deleted. Again, this is just conjecture.

Comment: _Delete the pointer to rightChild_ no, delete right child aka where rightChild pointed to.

Comment: _change the root to y_ delete where root pointed to and set the pointer to y.

Comment: If you rotate nodes and the nodes are stored in unique_ptr, I would expect to see std::move in your code. It looks like you take the raw pointer out of an unique_ptr and put it into another one.